# MSDEPLOY unable to contact remote temporary agent

Tags: iis-7.5, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I have been running an MSDEPLOY command successfully for the past couple weeks until yesterday (at least that's when I was first made aware of the deploy script failure).  I did install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 on the build server yesterday to fix an issue related to web.config transformations, and I do run the MSDEPLOY script from that server to install on a remote server (running Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5).

I stepped up the MSDEPLOY command to verbose and got the following trace:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='E:\Staging\ChildSupportWebsite.Beta1\Release\_PublishedWebsites\Csws.UI_Package\Csws.UI.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='HFSWP121-03720',userName='DOMAIN\USERNAME',password='PASSWORD',includeAcls='False',tempAgent='true' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"E:\Staging\ChildSupportWebsite.Beta1\sit.Csws.UI.SetParameters.xml" -skip:Directory="Csws\\Participant" -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="bin\\.*.xml|pdb"  -whatif  -verbose
Verbose: Using ID '557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' for connections to the remote server.
Verbose: Creating temporary directory '\\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' on remote target.
Verbose: Copying temporary agent file C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Delegation.dll to \\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d\Microsoft.Web.Delegation.dll.
Verbose: Copying temporary agent file C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll to \\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll.
Verbose: Copying temporary agent file C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\MsDepSvc.exe to \\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d\MsDepSvc.exe.
Verbose: Copying temporary agent file C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\x64\axnative.dll to \\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d\x64\axnative.dll.
Verbose: Copying temporary agent file C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\x86\axnative.dll to \\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d\x86\axnative.dll.
Verbose: Executing command line 'C:\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d\MsDepSvc.exe -listenUrl:http://+:80/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d/' on remote target.
Verbose: Temporary agent started on remote target. Process ID 2592.Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Verbose: The temporary deployment agent at 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' could not be contacted. It may still be starting up. The connection will be attempted again.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Verbose: The temporary deployment agent at 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' could not be contacted. It may still be starting up. The connection will be attempted again.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Verbose: The temporary deployment agent at 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' could not be contacted. It may still be starting up. The connection will be attempted again.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Verbose: The temporary deployment agent at 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' could not be contacted. It may still be starting up. The connection will be attempted again.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Verbose: The temporary deployment agent at 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' could not be contacted. It may still be starting up. The connection will be attempted again.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Verbose: Performing synchronization pass #1.
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'http://HFSWP121-03720/557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' as 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'.
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Verbose: Terminating the temporary agent process (ID 2592) on the remote target.

Verbose: Deleting temporary directory '\\HFSWP121-03720\C$\Windows\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\557f88cc-6194-41fb-84b0-6895fe8bc47d' on remote target.

Error: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions' to type 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions'.
Error count: 1.
```

I have googled this but I have not found any information that can get me to a resolution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: I spent a few hours with Microsoft tech support on the phone.  We were not able to come to a resolution on this.  The workaround, for the time being, is to install the Web Deployment Agent on the remote machine and to use that instead of the temp agent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone out there who has been using this from the command line, it may be that you have both v1 and v2 installed in which case change

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" in the command line to

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy v2\msdeploy.exe"

It fixed this issue for me. Hope that helps.

Comment: True.  I should have specified we'd looked at that also.  By default, the Visual Studio-generated *.cmd file uses V1 so if using the generated files, they must be modified to use V2.

Incidentally, Web Deploy 3.0 is still in beta (but it fixes the issue as outlined in the question).